# req.body gets undefined when forwarded to another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

the code looks like this

---

### saleComponent.html

---

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #salesdetails="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(salesdetails.value)">
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let label of labels">
            <label for="item1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{label}}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" value="" name="{{label}}" id="item1" ngModel>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

---

### SaleComponent.ts

---

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { SalesService } from '../sales.service';
import { Sale } from '../model/sale';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sales',
  templateUrl: 'frontend/js/sales/sales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['frontend/js/sales/sales.component.css']
})
export class SalesComponent implements OnInit {
    form;
    labels;
    sales : Sale[];

    constructor(private salesService: SalesService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.getLabels();
    }

    getLabels(){
        this.salesService.getLables().subscribe(labels => {
            this.labels = labels[0].attributes;
            console.log(labels);
        });

    }

    getSales(){

    }


    onSubmit(formValues){
        this.salesService.addSale(formValues).subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
}
```

---

### SaleService.ts

---

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Sale } from './model/sale';

@Injectable()
export class SalesService {
  private lablesUrl = "/sale/labels";
  private saleUrl = "/sale";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getLables(){
    return this.http.get(this.lablesUrl);
  }

  addSale(formValues){
    return this.http.post(this.saleUrl, formValues);
  }

  getSales(): Observable<Sale[]> {
    let sales = this.http.get<Sale[]>(this.saleUrl/*, this.authservice.options*/);
    console.log(sales)
    return sales;
  }

  deleteItems(idArray){
    return this.http.delete(this.saleUrl,idArray/*, this.authservice.options*/);
  }

}
```

### routefile.js

---

route.post('/sale', saleDao.postSale);

### saleDao.js

---

in saleDao.js a fucntion is present named postSale inside which a fucntion is present name modifyLabels() like this.

```
function postSale(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);//output the body of the request
    utility.modifyLabels(req);
}
```

---

### utility.js

```
function modifyLabels(req){
   console.log(req.body); //outputs undefined;
}
```

I dont know why req.body is showing this behaviour

Comment: Is that the entirety of the code or did you remove some stuff for simplicity?

Comment: ya i removed some stuff for simplicity but actually i have described the problem as it is

Comment: Do you use body-parser?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma As I responded to Bhojendra, the problem appears to be related to scope and garbage collection.  We would need to see more code to verify if that is indeed the case.

Comment: This is the whole code @BShaps

Comment: actually problem is solved now. But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The data was being cleared for some reason and got nothing there. To solve, I used `JSON` object like following:

```
function postSale(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);//output the body of the request
    utility.modifyLabels(JSON.stringify(req));
}

function modifyLabels(req){
   console.log(JSON.parse(req).body);
}
```

I hope this would be helpful to you as well.

Comment: The reason appears to be a scope issue which is why I asked if it was the entirety of the code.  If I'm right, the reason why your code would work is that you're actually creating a new object in memory when you JSON.stringify the req.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.